# why ">" to overwrite log does not work with me?

Tags: linux

i try to overwrite progress in file , but without success, it still append the line to file , any help can be appreciated

```
dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=/root/Desktop/partition2.img bs=4096 status=progress > test.t5
```

the output

```
482164736 bytes (482 MB, 460 MiB) copied, 1 s, 476 MB/s
492519424 bytes (493 MB, 470 MiB) copied, 2 s, 246 MB/s
502874112 bytes (503 MB, 480 MiB) copied, 3 s, 167 MB/s
512311296 bytes (512 MB, 489 MiB) copied, 4 s, 128 MB/s
523321344 bytes (523 MB, 499 MiB) copied, 5 s, 105 MB/s
534200320 bytes (534 MB, 509 MiB) copied, 6 s, 88.9 MB/s
544686080 bytes (545 MB, 519 MiB) copied, 7 s, 77.8 MB/s
555565056 bytes (556 MB, 530 MiB) copied, 8 s, 69.4 MB/s
566312960 bytes (566 MB, 540 MiB) copied, 9 s, 62.9 MB/s
576012288 bytes (576 MB, 549 MiB) copied, 10 s, 57.6 MB/s
586629120 bytes (587 MB, 559 MiB) copied, 11 s, 53.2 MB/s
596852736 bytes (597 MB, 569 MiB) copied, 12 s, 49.7 MB/s
607469568 bytes (607 MB, 579 MiB) copied, 13 s, 46.7 MB/s
617693184 bytes (618 MB, 589 MiB) copied, 14 s, 44.1 MB/s
627916800 bytes (628 MB, 599 MiB) copied, 15 s, 41.9 MB/s
638140416 bytes (638 MB, 609 MiB) copied, 16 s, 39.9 MB/s
649019392 bytes (649 MB, 619 MiB) copied, 17 s, 38.2 MB/s
659898368 bytes (660 MB, 629 MiB) copied, 18 s, 36.6 MB/s
670646272 bytes (671 MB, 640 MiB) copied, 19 s, 35.3 MB/s
680214528 bytes (680 MB, 649 MiB) copied, 20 s, 34.0 MB/s
690438144 bytes (690 MB, 658 MiB) copied, 21 s, 32.9 MB/s
700923904 bytes (701 MB, 668 MiB) copied, 22 s, 31.8 MB/s
710754304 bytes (711 MB, 678 MiB) copied, 23 s, 30.9 MB/s
721240064 bytes (721 MB, 688 MiB) copied, 24 s, 30.0 MB/s
731987968 bytes (732 MB, 698 MiB) copied, 25 s, 29.3 MB/s
```

thank you all

Comment: It works exactly as designed. All output gets written to the file; it just doesn't reset the start position like a terminal does - files don't have 2 dimensions and cursors for write positions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe the redirection operator `>` opens the file, writes all output to it, then closes the file. I don't think it closes the file after each newline and then overwrites it with the next. As in, it will continue appending the output of the command to the same file until the command finishes. If you `>` into that same file again, *then* the file will be overwritten with the new output.

It's not clear what you're trying to do here. If you just want to watch the progress via the file for some reason, you can use [`tail -f`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html), or to get just the most recent (last) line, you can use [`tail -n1`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html).

Comment: thank you all tail -f work fine for me , i do not know how tail option pass my mind